# How to update theme-color in application like angular

Tags: angular, meta

How can we update the theme color dynamically inside the head tag using angular 4 applications.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">
```

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**
Better solution suggested by Debmallya Bhattacharya :

Using the [updateTag from the Angular Meta service](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta#updateTag) :

```
this.meta.updateTag({ content: color }, 'name=theme-color');
```

[Running example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52781284-2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmeta-color.service.ts)

**Old answer :**
I would simply create a service for that and do some javascript ([javascript code got from here](https://gordonlesti.com/change-theme-color-via-javascript/)):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MetaColorService {
  changeThemeColor(color: string) {
    const metaThemeColor = document
    .querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]");
    metaThemeColor.setAttribute("content", color);
  }
}
```

[Running test to run on mobile device.](https://stackoverflow-52781284.stackblitz.io)

[Editable version of the example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52781284)

Comment: Couldn't you use the Meta service provided by angular? https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta

Comment: @DebmallyaBhattacharya I updated my answer, thank's for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm implementing it as we speak, and it works like a charm. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The revised solution does answer the question true to the "Angular Way™".